# Excel is not running any code with .Autofilter present. It also appears to not be recording macros correctly

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I got a new laptop at work and it will not run the macros in a macro enabled workbook I created.  It gives a "Run-time error '9': subscript out of range" error on every line that has .AutoFilter involved.

both versions of excel are the same Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 version, all security settings are the same, all windows/pc settings are the same.  the macro will run in the book just fine on other computers too.

I also am having an issue with Excel just not recording macros, which may or may not be related.  When I try to record a new macro that sets an autofilter on a row it just makes a red ., nothing else in the macro code other than the Sub/End Sub part and the three ' with the name and hot key.

I have been searching all MS documentation and through these and other forums and have not found a solution that works.

This is what it looks like when I try to record a simple macro to set autofilter on row 2.  it just puts a red period where the next part for the autofilter should be.

```
Sub filtertest1()
'
' filtertest1 Macro
'

'
    Rows("2:2").Select
    .
End Sub
```

I just need to figure out what the heck is going on and why I cannot run this one very basic piece of code and why I cannot record new macros.

Comment: Try reinstalling your Office package

Comment: Yes, definitely looks like it needs a clean re-install.

Comment: i am looking into that now though as i have exhausted myself trying to figure this out.  thank you for suggestions!